# PHP7 Symfony4 Phpdocumentor

Tags: symfony4, phpdoc

Is there posible to use PhpDocumentor under above/titled?
When I trying instal it with composer it shows me:

```
$ composer require --dev phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor dev-master
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.1.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor dev-master -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor[dev-master].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor dev-master requires symfony/config ~2.3 -> no matching package found.
```

So how to do it or how to document code?

Comment: Try to remove `dev-master` from `composer require` command. Composer will match newest compatible stable version of phpdocumentator for your project.

Comment: You can also try to install `dev-develop` instead of `dev-master`. It looks like `dev-master` version is not the latest up to date dev branch.

Comment: @Jakub Matczak unfortunatelly none of above works for me...

Comment: Did you try installing symfony/config first with `composer require symfony/config`?

Comment: @Dirk, I have installed Symfony4 but rather with way described on Symfony`s page: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html -with: composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project

Answer (score 0):

Due to incompatible internal requirements of phpDocumentor, Composer cannot install both it and newer Symfony versions. As such, the phpDocumentor team recommends using their PHAR rather than using it from a Composer-managed installation.